# Scaling navigation height based on page location

Tags: jquery, html, css, wordpress, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to create a navigation that grows when your at the top of the screen, and shrink as you scroll down (popular on many sites.

I have an example that I found which is close to what I want

http://jsfiddle.net/seancannon/npdqa9ua/

my HTML

```
<div class="container-fluid">
<div class="row">

    <div class="col-md-12" data-0="opacity:1;" data-75="opacity:0;">

    <nav class="navbar navbar-custom" role="navigation">

         <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->

            <div class="navbar-header">

                <a class="navbar-brand" href="<?php echo home_url(); ?>"></a>        

                <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse"> 
                    <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span> 
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span> 
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span> 
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span> 
                </button> 

            </div>

        <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling --> 

            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse navbar-right"> 
                <?php /* Primary navigation */
                    wp_nav_menu( array(
                    'menu' => 'top_menu',
                    'depth' => 2,
                    'container' => false,
                    'menu_class' => 'nav navbar-nav',
                    //Process nav menu using our custom nav walker
                    'walker' => new wp_bootstrap_navwalker())
                    );
                ?>
            </div>
    </nav>

        <div class="hr"></div>

    </div>

</div><!-- /row --> 
</div><!-- /container -->
```

I want it to work with the responsiveness of my Wordpress and Bootstrap 3 default navigation that I am using. Adding a height to my current navigation stops the mobile navigation from opening. I'd prefer there not to be a defined height, my current nag-default height is based on padding above and below the links.

Comment: Do you want to have change only on `height`?

Comment: yes, I've seen plenty of sites where at the top of the site the header is large, then when you scroll down it becomes a narrow bar on top. I want similar, Eventually I will have my logo grow/shrink

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**HTML**

```
<body>
    <nav> <!-- menu elements --> </nav>
</body>
```

**CSS**

```
nav {            
    height: 200px;
    width: 100%;
    transition: height .5s;
}

nav.small {
    height: 50px;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
}
```

**JS**

```
var $window = $(window),
    $menu = $('nav'),
    windowWidth = $window.width();

$window.on('scroll', function(e) {
    if (windowWidth < 768) // maybe you calculate the width on `resizing` event
            return;
    var y = $window.scrollTop();
    if (y > 0 && $menu.hasClass('small'))
        return;
    $menu.toggleClass('small', y > 0);
});
```

Just for an idea, hope this help.

**UPDATE**

Just you need protect the code from < 768px, you can use [modernizr](http://modernizr.com) and check if user using mobile, don't run the code. or calculate `window width` by yourself. (as I added to code)

Comment: Can I put that in my functions.php. or does that need to go in <head> Also i'll give this a shot ASAP, I'll make sure to accept it if it works. Thank you

Comment: Which part? I didn't provide any sever-side code. you need to add `CSS` & `JS` part of my code and see if works for you.

Comment: the js part. I am using Wordpress and most of my functions are in the functions.php file

Comment: do you have any js file? I think you should add that lines to an js file and linked to the page, or add that block of code to the HTML side, maybe on <head> or some where else. (please note, if you add the code to <head> section, add `document.ready` too)

Comment: np bro, If something not working, feel free to add comment here and I'll answer asap !

Answer (score 0):

I would toggle a class ".short" based on screen position.(JS adding/removing class on scroll)

In the css I would use css3 transition (height) to get the growing effect.

I would use the @media to get this effect only in browsers bigger (min-width) than your setting mobile size.